# Excel - how to go to the bottom of two variable-length columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a two-column Excel table that looks like this:

```
Name | Email
1    | 1.1
2    |
3    | 3.1
     | 3.2
     | 3.3
4    |
```

How can I get to the **left cell underneath the lower of the two columns** if I don't know where the cursor is?

Note: the two columns may be of variable length. Either column may contain the lowest value.

Plus points if your solution works on Excel Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Macro solution

Tested to work on Excel for Mac 2011. It assumes your data starts at cell A1.

```
Sub SelectLeftCell()

  Dim LastRow As Long

  LastRow = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
  Range("A" & LastRow).Select

End Sub
```

## Non-macro solution

Tested to work on Excel for Mac 2011. It assumes your data starts at cell A1.

1. fn + cmd + left arrow (to move to cell A1)
2. cmd + a (to select the current region)
3. control + period (to move to the right top corner of the selection)
4. control + period (to move to the right bottom corner of the selection)
5. control + period (to move to the left bottom corner of the selection)

Comment: Thank you, very helpful! I'm using the non-macro solution (easier). +1 as well for the 'Ctrl+.', which I didn't know about.

Comment: For reference, Windows version: Ctrl-Home > Ctrl-A > Ctrl-Period > Ctrl-Period > Ctrl-Period

Answer (score 0):

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("#",IF(F14>G14,ADDRESS(AGGREGATE(14, 6, 1+ ROW(A1:Z200)/(B1:B200<>""), 1), COLUMN(B1), 1, 1),ADDRESS(AGGREGATE(14, 6, 1+ ROW(A1:Z200)/(D1:D200<>""), 1), COLUMN(D1), 1, 1))),"Link Name")
```

Solution assumes your data is in columns B and D.

Don't have mac so you'll have to check it out. If it doesn't run for you I will set you up with alternative formulas to do the same thing.

You have to make according adjustments to columns and ranges I'm only looking in A1 to Z200.
This method can be expanded to service more columns but it will get quite larger without exporting some of the stuff to a service space.

Basically the aggregate finds the last entry, the 1+ offsets the result to the next row, and you have two aggregates comparing which column has a the furthest value. depending on which column has the furthest value. There might be a better re-design of this idea but its still is a regular formula solution.
You can also insert the file path in the concatenation to make this link usable in other sheets in the document.